# Why cannot I see QGraphicsLineItem when added to QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to add `QGraphicsLineItem` to `QGraphicsScene` and display it in `QGraphicsView`. But when I compile and run the below code, it just shows white blank screen and I am not able to see any line on it. What do you think I am doing wrong?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>

class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
   MyGraphicsView()  {
       _scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,1024,800);
       setScene(_scene);
   }

   virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
   {
      QGraphicsLineItem *line = new QGraphicsLineItem(100.0,100.0,500.0,500.0);
      line->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3, Qt::SolidLine));
      line->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
      _scene->addItem(line);
   }


private:
   QGraphicsScene* _scene;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   MyGraphicsView cw;
   cw.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so, the problem is, you create a line and add it to the scene each time the paint event is triggered. I am not certain what is happening under the hood but the first time the QGraphicsView is drawn on the screen the line is not present in the scene. Then you probably enter some kind of infinite loop where the painting of the widget trigger a line to be added to the scene, which is turn trigger a repaint...

Comment: Instead you probably want a dedicated function to instance and manage the scene, which you call before entering the main event loop and drawing your widget.

Comment: yeah .. it seems like even defining the function `paintEvent`  with nothing on it cause line to not get drawn. So, I added another function which adds the line. Then I called that function in main. That seem to work. Thank you.